# How to expect a function call to not emit an event in foundry

Tags: events, foundry

I have the following function:

```
function doStuff() external {
        emit MyEvent();
    }
```

And in my foundry tests, I want to check to make sure this event was NOT emitted. How do I do that?

Answer (score 2):

There isn't way to check if an event is NOT emitted, but for your purpose you can use `vm.getRecordedLogs();` and assert that the length of the logs array is 0.

```
function testDoesNotEmit() public {
Vm.Log[] memory entries = vm.getRecordedLogs();
 
//
// Code that does not emit event
// 

assertEq(entries.length, 0); 
}
```